# PL/SQL Insert procedure, insert if the row doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Below is my procedure. It inserts, but every time I execute the procedure it inserts a duplicated row. I don't want that, but i have tried everything and I don't know how to resolve the issue.

My Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Insert_Cidades(p_NOME CIDADE.NOME_CIDADE%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO CIDADE(COD_CIDADE,NOME_CIDADE) VALUES(seq_id_cidade.NEXTVAL,p_NOME);
END Insert_Cidades;
/
```

This is in pl/slq oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO CIDADE
USING (SELECT p_NOME as NOME FROM DUAL) x
ON (x.NOME = NOME_CIDADE)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (COD_CIDADE, NOME_CIDADE)
  VALUES (seq_id_cidade.NEXTVAL, p_NOME)
```

or

```
INSERT INTO CIDADE
SELECT
  seq_id_cidade.NEXTVAL, 
  p_NOME
FROM
  dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM CIDADE WHERE NOME_CIDADE = p_NOME)
```

Note that the comparison `NOME_CIDADE = p_NOME` is case sensitive, meaning that you can still insert 'John', 'john', 'JOHN' and 'jOHN'. If you don't want that, change it to something like `upper(NOME_CIDADE) = upper(p_NOME)` or `nlssort(NOME_CIDADE) = nlssort(p_NOME)`.

Comment: WHEN _NOT_ MATCHED :-)